# Azure Logic App - expected failure in request causes entire run to be "failed"

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a scenario where I will be making a third party API request to check if a particular set of data exists, however in the event that it doesn't the request returns a 404.

That's fine, and I can react accordingly using the "run after failure" condition in the logic app, however in the Overview of the logic app the entire run will be interpreted as a failure due to the 404 returned from that initial API request.

Is there any way I can instruct the logic app that a bad response from a particular request is acceptable? And shouldn't be interpreted as the entire logic app run being a fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a decision or case action after the API request that will run both on success and failure of the API request.

Check the return code of the API request and use the terminate action to set the desired logic app result.

Comment: Originally I was using a decision case on the return of the third party API request but due to it returning a 404 it seemed to cease executing subsequent actions.

The only way I could get around this was to use the "run after" option and select "failure" for the actions following third party API request to handle that case.

All those subsequent actions do execute as expected but the logic app thinks it has failed as a whole (i.e. on the overview screen) presumably due to the "failed" third party API request.

Comment: That seems strange. I have a simillar logic in one of my flows. I did use parallel actions and scope within each parallel branch. One branch has my processing scope that runs after a success of the previous action. The other parallel branch has an exception handling scope that runs on a failure of the previous call. Works fine here.

Comment: Have a look at the "Terminate"-action. There you can set the end state of your logic app run. That's what I use in my Exception Handling scope as well

Comment: Thanks Steven - "Terminate" was exactly what I was looking for! I've ended up using that after creating the parallel branches for success/fail of the prior API call.

Comment: I have this same problem. I do not feel like i should have to force a successful termination when I am handling a run-after failure condition successfully.